# Factorizing implementations of pure, virtual functions for a subset of classes

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have this class hierarchy:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo(Base *b) = 0;
};

class B {
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};


class C : public A, public B {
public:
    virtual void viz() = 0;
};

class E : public C {
public:
    /** Some non-pure virtual functions, does not implement foo */
};

class F : public E {
    /** does not implement foo */
}

class G : public E {
    /** does not implement foo */
}
```

Now, I would like to define derived, "templatized" versions of F and G, which declares a method `foo(T *s)` and where the implementation of `foo(Base *s)` simply calls foo(T *s) by applying a static_cast.

Moreover, I don't wan to expose the template arguments to A, because users of these interfaces (A, B, C, E) should not be exposed to the template parameters (I'm writing a plugin architecture and user-types that derives a given interface are passed back and forth from plugins to base system).

What I thought was to define this class:

```
template <typename T>
class GA : public A{
...
}
```

and to define the "templatized" derivations of F and G like this:

```
template <typename T>
class GF : public F, public GA {
...
}
```

the problem is that GF sees two different declarations of foo() (one given by A, the other by GA), so the compiler throws me an error when I try to instantiate GF because foo(Base) is not defined.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `Impl` inherits class `A` and class `C` inherits both `Impl` and `A`. This means there will be two instances of class `A` where first A's `foo` is implemented by `Impl` and a seconds one is still pure virtual. Virtual inheritance can solve this problem, for example:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo () = 0;
};

class Impl : virtual public A {
public:
    virtual void foo () {}
};

class C
    : virtual public A
    , public Impl
{
};
```

Comment: +1 that's what I wanted to write, but it seems you were faster

Comment: @akappa: A couple of details: You do not need to inherit publicly from `Impl` (unless you want for some particular reason). This depends on all of the objects that use `Impl` inheriting *virtually* from `A` (or you will hit the same problem again). Finally this modifies the layout of the objects and adds a bit of space cost. Virtual inheritance implies that the unique `A` is not in a well known location at any given point in the hierarchy, and that in turn requires the addition of a hidden *pointer-to-A* to the objects and the dereference of that pointer on each member access. Details.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need multiple inheritance?  Why not just `class C : public Impl { ... }`?

Comment: I've changed the question a bit after posting it and now it doesn't make sense, as you correctly pointed out :) I'm gonna edit it to reflect better the problem I have in my application

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something different. Declare the function as a pure virtual function, and then just trivially implement it in the derived classes by forwarding the call:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
void A::foo() {}

class B : public A {
   void foo() { A::foo(); }
};
```

But that does not mean that you cannot achieve what you are trying to do. If you want to implement that operation in another class and use inheritance, you can do it in two different ways:

Intermediate type:

Implement an intermediate type that provides the functionality, then each derived type can extend either the original `A` or the intermediate `I` type:

```
class I : public A {
public:
   void foo() {}
};
class B : public I {};      // inherits the implementation
class C : public A {        // needs to provide it's own implementation
   void foo() {}
};
```

Virtual inheritance:

Alternatively you can use virtual inheritance (of the three options I would avoid this). In this way you can create a hierarchy where `V` inherits virtually from `A` and provides the implementation. The rest of the classes can either inherit from `A` directly or inherit from `A` virtually and also inherit from `V`. By using virtual inheritance you ensure that there is a single `A` subobject in your hierarchy:

```
class V : public virtual A {
public:
   void foo() {}
};
class B : public virtual A, V { // Inheritance from V is a detail, can be private
                                // no need to provide foo
};
```

Note that this approach is overkill for this particular limited problem, and that it has side effects (the layout of the objects will be different and they will be slightly bigger in size). Again, unless you want to mix and match functions from different *sibling* classes, I would avoid this.

What was wrong in your code

The problem in your code is that you are inheriting from `A` multiple times, one through `D` and another directly. While in the path from `D` the virtual function is no longer pure, in the direct path from `A` the virtual function is still undefined.

That also causes the second issue in the error message: ambiguity. Because there are two `A` subobjects, when you try to call `foo` on the most derived type, the compiler cannot figure out on which of the two `A` subobjects you want to execute the request. The same type of ambiguity problems would arise if you tried to cast from the most derived type into `A` directly, as the compiler would not know to which `A` you want to refer.

Answer (score 1):

Impl does not implement A's method in D and C, it's a completely different base.

You should derive Impl from A, then derive every class of that subset from Impl instead of A.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inherit from both the A and Impl, then you need to use virtual inheritance.

Edit:

See @Vlad's answer for more details.